# ASP.net PageMethods return undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, computer-science, pagemethods

Hi everyone i trying to get data from cs to js using ToolkitScriptManager.
this is my aspx :

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../assets/lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        $(window).load(function () {
            alert(PageMethods.isConnected());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server"
            EnablePageMethods="true"
            EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my code behind

```
[ScriptMethod, WebMethod]
        public static bool isConnected()
        {
            return true;
        }
```

i dont know, but this keep result undefined, sorry if this is really simple problem for you, but for me so hard, because i am new in asp.net
please help me to fix this problem.

Comment: Look at this : http://forums.asp.net/t/993893.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a **success and a failure callback** to the webmethod call as below.

```
  $(window).load(function () {
                                    PageMethods.isConnected(fnsuccesscallback,fnerrorcallback);

        });
        function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            alert(data);

        }
        function fnerrorcallback(result) {
            alert(result.statusText);
        }
```

Also, there is another way of accessing the page methods using $.ajax.

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="../assets/lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

         $(window).load(function () {

      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageMethodTest.aspx/isConnected",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: fnsuccesscallback,
            error:fnerrorcallback
        });
    });            function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
            alert(data.d);

        }
        function fnerrorcallback(result) {
            alert(result.statusText);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager EnablePageMethods="true" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will do 100% work

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
       function Generate()
       {              
           var result = PageMethods.GenerateOTP(your parameter, function (response)
           {
               alert(response);
           });
       }
</script>
```