# javascript PageMethods in ASP.NET - passing a parameter

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

From another posting ([ASP.net PageMethods return undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19580633/asp-net-pagemethods-return-undefined)) I know that I need to  supply a success and a failure callback to the webmethod call as below. However I need to also pass in a 2nd parameter to the failure callback fnerrorcallback but I can't access this parameter and the result.

```
$(window).load(function () {
   PageMethods.isConnected(fnsuccesscallback,fnerrorcallback);
});
function fnsuccesscallback(data) {
   alert(data);
}
function fnerrorcallback(result) {
   alert(result.statusText);
}
```

Comment: Are you decorating your code-behind method with [System.Web.Services.WebMethod()] ? Show it.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are looking for `userContext` if you want to pass param to failure callback from `javascript`, take a look at this:

```
$(window).load(function () {

        var userContext = { name: "something", value: "something" };
        PageMethods.isConnected(successHandler, failedHandler, userContext);
    });

    function failedHandler(message, userContext) {
    };

    function successHandler(result, userContext, method) {
    };
```

Comment: thanks this looks promising but do you have an example of how to access the userContext in the failedHandler?

Comment: !!! its not clear? when you call `PageMethods.isConnected` in `load` handler, pass your object which you want to access to it from `failed` and `success` handler, above i call it `userContext`, then this object is passed to `failed` and `success` handler as second `argument`

Answer (score 0):

I think that solution is here: http://aspalliance.com/1922_PageMethods_In_ASPNET_AJAX.3

so your call should be like this:

```
PageMethods.isConnected(params, fnsuccesscallback,fnerrorcallback, yourContext);
```