# Jquery validation in login form asp.net c# with webservice

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services

Hello i have created a login form in asp.net to redirect another page i have created a webservice for user validation and jquery but ajax data is returning undefined page is not redirecting please help me ... my code is like this

**Webservice**

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static string LoginSer(string un,string pwd)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username,Password from emp_Login where IsActive=1 and Username='" + un + "' and Password='" + pwd + "'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "0";
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
    var uid = $("#txtUN").attr('value');
    var pass = $("#txtPWD").attr('value');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx/LoginSer",
        data: '{un: ' + uid + ', pwd: ' + pass + '}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d == "1")
            {
                window.location.assign("../../Home.aspx");
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }

    });

});
});
```

Comment: Apparently your code is correct. Have you debugged the input and output of your Webservice?

Comment: I checked with debug no error but it is not redirecting value is getting null only

Comment: Does "data" in success is null ? If yes....press f12 in your browser to check any error in console.

Comment: data is getting as undefined ....

Comment: No error is console ... but data is getting as undefined

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19581868/2238515

Comment: I have seen that post i used that code but the value is getting undefined only

Comment: check my answer below.

Comment: I got it .. I just removed contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By removing contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

i have got it ...

Successfully running ...

Answer (score 0):

I think your URL in ajax call is incorrect. You need to provide your service name, such as Login.asmx, and not the page (I.e. Login.aspx).

I am also not sure about the way you are passing data, it may be correct though.

.

Answer (score 0):

These are mistakes which u made

1. Parameters name mismatch
2. Passing as Data
3. Format in the **data** of POST method was havig mismatched quotes.

Web api method contains **un** & **pwd** as your parameters, which means your are supposed to request this call with **query strings** like

**?un=Name&pwd=Pass**

Next you are calling the service and sending as a **data**  which will look for a object containing same properties as that of ur input data.

One Solution
   public class Login
   {
        public string un { get; set; } 
        public string pwd { get; set; }
   }

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string LoginSer(Login user)
    {

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Username,Password from emp_Login where IsActive=1 and Username='" + user.un + "' and Password='" + user.pwd + "'", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return "1";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "0";
                }
            }
        }

    }

$(document).ready(function () {
$("#btnLogin").click(function () {
    var uid = $("#txtUN").attr('value');
    var pass = $("#txtPWD").attr('value');
    var userdata = {
            "un": uid,
            "pwd": pass
        };      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Login.aspx/LoginSer",
        data: userdata,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.d == "1")
            {
                window.location.assign("../../Home.aspx");
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            //alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            var err = eval("(" + XMLHttpRequest.responseText + ")");
            alert(err.Message);
        }

    });

});
});
```

The other solution is simple fix by passing values into querystring by using

```
window.href
```

Comment: Hi aravind ... the value am getting is undefined when am printing it in alert box from jquery

Comment: Like this alert(data.d);